# Dynamically change custom Views of TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` in my Android app. It is set up with an icon with some text below for each tab. What I want to do now is to change the color of the selected tab so that it stands out a bit more. The icons are gray, but I want the selected tab to be green. For this I have a separate `Drawable` (png file) for each color.

It kinda works, but it *adds* a new `View` to the tab at every select/unselect instead of changing it. Here is the code in question (this is a custom `Fragment` class):

```
private ViewPager           mViewPager;
private MyPagerAdapter      mAdapter;
private TabLayout           mTabLayout;
private int                 mCurrentItem = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_tablayout);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    final MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
    mCurrentItem = 0;

    mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), myActivity);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentItem);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mTabLayout.removeAllTabs();
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab()
                .setTag(0)
                .setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_tab_recipes_selected));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab()
                .setTag(1)
                .setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_tab_shopping_list));

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
            if (tab.getTag() == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch ((TabConstants.TAGS) tab.getTag())
            {
                case 0:
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_tab_recipes_selected);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_tab_shopping_list_selected);
            }

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            myActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // Invalidate Toolbar
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);
            if (tab == null || tab.getTag() == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch ((TabConstants.TAGS) tab.getTag())
            {
                case 0:
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_tab_recipes);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_tablayout_shopping_list);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here are a few images of what's happening. The right `View` is inflated every time, but it is *added* instead of *replacing* the previous `View`.

**Initially:**

[image]

**First tab change:**

[image]

**Second tab change:**

[image]

## Update (solution):

Here is an example of the `StateListDrawable` I ended up using for the tabs.

**Drawables:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item   android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item   android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/unselected" />

    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item   android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />

</selector>
```

**Text colors:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item   android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:color="@color/my_selected_color" />

    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item   android:state_selected="false"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:color="@color/my_unselected_color" />

    <!-- Pressed tab -->
    <item   android:state_pressed="true"
            android:color="@color/my_selected_color" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `StateListDrawable` for your images within each tab.

For example, let's say in your `my_tablayout_tab_recipes` there is your *knife and spoon* image.

You should assign an xml file as a background for that image, in which you could decide the *selected* and *unselected* version of your image.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

There's no need to change by yourself the background images for selected and unselected state; the android system will take care of that for you.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know about the `StateListDrawable`. I found a good description of the usage for `TabLayout`s [here](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136).

Comment: I added a couple of examples of what worked for me for the custom `View`s of my `TabLayout`, in case anyone else stumbles in here later.